# Are all relations that are symmetric and anti-symmetric a subset of the reflexive relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

Simple question, but I can't seem to find a guaranteed answer. A symmetric set contains `(a, b)` if it contains `(b, a)`, but an anti-symmetric set only contains `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` when `a = b`. It seems to me like the only time a set can be anti-symmetric and symmetric is if it is a subset of the reflexive set. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a relation on $A$ such that it's both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Let $(x,y)\in R$. Then by symmetry, $(y,x)\in R$ and by anti-symmetry, $x=y$.